# Facing a problem with python Tkinter calculator application

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I am a beginner to python I am trying to create a calculator application using Tkinter
So I have used for loop to create buttons and when I pass `lambda:onclick(i)` in for loop all the buttons are being assigned only to the last value of my iterable
This is my code.Please help me

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title('Simple Calculator!')

e=tk.Entry(root,width=35,borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=10,pady=10)

def onclick(number):
    curr=e.get()
    e.delete(0,'end')
    e.insert(0,str(curr)+str(number))

def onclick4():
    pass
def onclick3():
    e.delete(0,'end')
l=[]

w=0
for i in range(0,10):

    l.append(tk.Button(root,text=str(i),command=lambda:onclick(i),padx=40,pady=30))
    w=w+1
l.append(tk.Button(root,text='+',command=lambda:onclick('+'),padx=40,pady=30))
l.append(tk.Button(root,text='clrscr',command=onclick3,padx=40,pady=30))

a=0
for k in range(1,5):
    for j in range(0,3):
        l[a].grid(row=k,column=j)
        a+=1

l.append(tk.Button(root,text='=',command=onclick4,padx=100,pady=30))    
l[-1].grid(row=5,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function uses late binding which means it will use the last value of `i`.

You can bind early by assigning `i` as a default parameter:

```
lambda i=i: onclick(i)
```